# group mysql results into two separate divs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a mysql query that retrieves all my topic results. I then have a pagination system where results are separated into pages and the query's `limit #,#` changes based on what page you are on.

What I want to do is put all those results into two separate div containers. I want 21 results on each page. The first 9 I will put in one div. The next 12 will go in the other. Does anyone know an efficient way to do this? Should I use two queries, or javascript, or another way? I am just looking for the best most efficient way to do this. Unfortunately the pagination system makes two queries difficult. Any suggestions highly appreciated.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM topics LIMIT ?,?";
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt2->execute(array(somenumber,somenumber2));
```

Comment: Are you asking how to loop through your SQL query results? Because you could simply have a loop counter `$i` and `if ($i >= 9) {.. }`. Right?

Comment: @rfausak make that an answer, I wanted to say that but since you were first..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason why you can't do a single MySQL query and use JavaScript to sort the results. Understand that I don't understand here what your data is coming back looking like, so any example I provide will have to remain pretty agnostic in this regard.

I will, however, assert as an assumption that you have a JavaScript array of length 21 with some data that is the basis for your display.

Assuming that we're just talking about the first 9, and the last 12, the sorting code is as simple as:

```
// assume my_array is the array mentioned above
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i += 1) {
    var html = code_to_transform_data_from_array(array[i]);
    $('.div1').append($(html));
}
for (var i = 9; i < 21; i += 1) {
    var html = code_to_transform_data_from_array_b(array[i]);
    $('.div2').append($(html));
}
```

If your sorting condition is any more complicated, then you'd be better off with something like...

```
while (my_array.length > 0) {
    var item = my_array.pop();
    if (sorting_condition) {
        $('.div1').append(f1(item));
    }
    else {
        $('.div2').append(f2(item));
    }
}
```

(In the second example, I became a lazy typist and assumed `f1` and `f2` to be complete transformation functions. `sorting_condition` is your criteria for determining in which bucket something goes.

Hope that sets you off on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for your time Luke. Appreciate it. +1 and answer awarded.